# Can't choose an option in a dynamically created droplist in code

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

StackOverflow has been really really helpful over the last few weeks, as I have been given a task to create a webpage in Javascript, a language I've never even considered I'd be using. Haha! Well! I've gotten this far. But ran into a little snag that I can't figure out.

I have lists of dynamically generated droplists, that need to be preassigned to a value that is passed through a cookie. But they don't seem to be responding...

```
                    var CO;
                    var options = [];
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    var select = document.getElementById("co");
                    CO = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(CO);
                    for (var j = 0; j < CO.length; j++)
                    {
                        console.log("Concept names being passed: " + CO[j].Name);
                        option.text = (j + 1) + ".) " + CO[j].Name;
                        option.value = j + 1;
                        console.log(option);                            
                        options.push(option.outerHTML);

                    }
                        console.log(options);                        
                        select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', options.join('\n'));
            document.getElementById('cl').selectedIndex = level;
            document.getElementById("co").selectedIndex = outcome;          ///WHY WON'T YOU WORK! THE OTHER ONE WORKS!!!
```

This is the output I get in the console for the array:

```
"<option value="1">1.) Using Seebox<…", "<option value="2">2.) Electricity v…", "<option value="3">3.) Voltage</opti…", "<option value="4">4.) DC and AC</op…", "<option value="5">5.) Switch</optio…", "<option value="6">6.) Ohms Law</opt…", "<option value="7">7.) Series Resist…", "<option value="8">8.) Capacitors</o…", "<option value="9">9.) Light Depende…", "<option value="10">10.) Fuses</opti…
```

I see they get truncated...
So here is a list of the first 5:

```
<option value="1">1.) Using Seebox</option><option value="2">2.) Electricity vs Electronics</option><option value="3">3.) Voltage</option><option value="4">4.) DC and AC</option><option value="5">5.) Switch</option>
```

I don't get it? Everything seems to be correct?
Is this the only way to do it?
Is there a better way?
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Iwan Greyling

Comment: Not enough code. Show the HTML, and where do you set value to `outcome` variable?

Comment: each j loop iteration you should create a new option, set the value and text properties, and append it to your select.  if outcome is the value of the preselected option you should set the value property of the select to outcome, not the selectedIndex property.

Comment: @MysterX The outcome variable is assigned to a cookie and the cookie is read correctly. The HTML is really minimal. But I'll post a segment. That should only make problems in generation though `<select id="co" name="conceptoutcome">
                            </select>`

Comment: @James The value property? But wouldn't that set the text of an element, rather than set the focus to it? Please explain? I also tried `document.getElementById("co").selectedValue = outcome` and a few others I could think about. Still no cigar...

Comment: [Value property of a select](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp)

Comment: Hi @James. Thanks again for taking the time to respond... That didn't seem to work. I tried reading the value from the droplist and hardcoding. One returns "Undefined" the other just does nothing. `console.log(ed);
                document.getElementById('cl').selectedIndex = level;
                document.getElementById("co").value = "5.) Switch";//document.getElementById('co').options[outcome].text;          ///WHY WON'T YOU WORK! THE OTHER ONE WORKS!!!
                console.log(outcome);`